# Can't mass-assign protected attributes regristration create devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

i use two resource devise, admin and user,
admin relationship with tatausaha and user relationship with guru

on admin relationship with tatausaha not error

but on user relationship with guru i have error Can't mass-assign protected attributes

on model user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :guru_attributes

  has_one :guru 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :guru

end
```

on model guru.rb

```
class Guru < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :namaguru, :nip, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
end
```

on registrationusers_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationusersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  layout :layout_by_resource3
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!
  before_filter :resource_name

  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_guru
  end

  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save
      if resource.is_a?(User)
        redirect_to new_userguru_registrationuser_path, :notice => "Guru was successfully created."
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => new_user_session_path
      end


    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end

  end


end
```

on routes.rb

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrationusers" }
```

and i got the error such as

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attribut
es: guru_attributes):
  app/controllers/registrationusers_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

if someone asks me why I do not use cancan or role user for devise? i want to try this.
how to fix my problem, can anyone help me? thank's

Comment: Did you save your `user.rb` file?

Comment: yes i did.. and restart rails, but not working

Comment: on rails console
:guru_attributes=>{:namaguru => "maman"}}   ←[1m←[36m (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mBEGIN←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (1.0ms)←[0m  COMMIT
=> {:guru_attributes=>{:namaguru=>"maman"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i have solved my problem 
add this on top def create

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.guru.update_attributes(params[:guru])
if @user.save && @user.guru.update_attributes(params[:guru])
```